# How to manage Activex events in JS without Object tag

Tags: javascript, c#, html, activex, webcam

Hi im developing activex control to manage webcam in IE, everything works but i need to refresh the image when a new frame is captures, up to now i display images on click, but i want to listen "Captured frame event" in JS to refresh my html view.

I have seen a lot of samples but all of these are using Object tag in html

```
<object id="Control" classid="CLSID:id"/>
    <script for="Control" event="myEvent()">
        alert("hello");
    </script>
```

is there a way to listen activex events using pure JS? using :

```
Ob = new ActivexObject('PROG.ID');
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up using timer, when i click enable button in the view i call the method startRecord, in this method i read Activex value every 70 ms, I would rather not use timer but it works.

```
private async startRecord() {
    while (this.banCapturing) {
      await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 70)); //14 ~ 15 fps
      this.foto = this.Ob.imageBase64; //Read Activex Value, DLL is updating imageBase64 on camera event.
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not working in purly JavaScript  you can only use [JScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/microsoft.jscript?view=netframework-4.8).
JScript only works in Internet Explorer and there it only works, if the user confirms to execute the scripts, ussualy you use it in an .hta [Hyper Text (Markup Language) Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application)
Example:

```
<script language="JScript">
    "use strict";
    function openFile(strFileName) {
        var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        var f = fso.OpenTextFile(strFileName, 1);
        if (f.AtEndOfStream) {
            return;
        }
        var file = f.ReadAll();
        f.close();
        return file;
    }
    
    function writeFile(filename, content) {
        var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        var f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename, 2, true);
        f.Write(content);
        f.Close();
    }
</script>
<script language="javascript">
    "use strict";
    var native_db;
    function init() {
        var file = openFile("./Natives.json");      
        native_db = JSON.parse(file);
        displayNamespaces();
    };
```

I also would have as alternate an example how it works in modern Browsers, if it helps you out there:

```
<video id="webcam"></video>
<input type="button" value="activate webcam" onclick="test()">
<script>
function test() {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true}).then((stream) => { // get access to webcam
    const videoElement = document.getElementById('webcam');
    videoElement.srcObject = stream; // set our stream, to the video element
    videoElement.play();
    // This creates a Screenshot on click, as you mentioned
    videoElement.addEventListener('click', function(event) { 
      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = videoElement.videoWidth;
      canvas.height = videoElement.videoHeight;
      const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      context.drawImage(videoElement, 0, 0, videoElement.videoWidth, videoElement.videoHeight);
      // you could just do this, to display the canvas:
      // document.body.appendChild(canvas);

      canvas.toBlob(function (blob) { // we automatlicly download the screenshot
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob); // creates a Datastream Handle Link in your Browser
        a.download = 'screenshot.png'; // the name we have to define here now, since it will not use the url name
        document.body.appendChild(a); // some Browsers don't like operating with Events of Objects which aren't on DOM 
        setTimeout(function() { // so we timeout a ms
          a.click(); // trigger the download
          URL.revokeObjectURL(a.href); // release the Handle
          document.body.removeChild(a); // remove the element again
        }, 1);
      });
    });
  }).catch(console.error);
}
</script>
```